# How do I make inserted data persist in Room database?

Tags: android, kotlin, insert, android-room, persistence

I am struggling with inserting permanent data into my prepopulated database.

[image: Screenshot of data being added into database]

Here is the code that adds the data into the database

```
dialogBinding.btnYes.setOnClickListener {
    val cantoneseWord = dialogBinding.etAddCantoneseWord.text.toString()
    val englishWord = dialogBinding.etAddEnglishWord.text.toString()
    when {
        dialogBinding.etAddCantoneseWord.text.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a Cantonese word/phrase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        dialogBinding.etAddEnglishWord.text.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a English word/phrase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else -> {
        val newWord = WordEntity(0, cantoneseWord, englishWord, true)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            // withContext(Dispatchers.IO) suspends the coroutine and switches the execution to a background thread pool provided by the 'Dispatchesr.IO' dispatcher.
            // This avoids blocking the main thread which could cause the UI to freeze or become unresponsive.
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                wordDao.addWord(newWord)
                setupWordRecyclerView(wordDao)
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this@SearchActivity, "Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        wordDialog.dismiss()
    }
    }
}
```

Here is the code to create the database

```
fun getInstance(context: Context): WordDatabase {
    synchronized(this) {
        var instance = INSTANCE

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                WordDatabase::class.java,
                "CantoWords"
            ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .createFromAsset("database/CantoWords_shortened.db").build()
            INSTANCE = instance
        }
        return instance
    }
}
```

I am able to successfully insert data into the database (as shown in the first screenshot ID 7 - Test), however if I restart the app, reinstall it or extract the database and view it on DB Browser for SQLite, ID 7 disappears.

Comment: have you tried to close the db before closing the app?

Comment: @RuiAlves Yes I have. An update: I've removed the fallbackToDestructiveMigration() and now the data persists even if I reopen the app. However, it still disappears when I reinstall the app.

Comment: "However, it still disappears when I reinstall the app". Reinstalling the App removes the App and clears the App's data and therefore the database and will there create the database by copying the database from the asset. The only you could persist the updates would be to save the updates outside of the App's data.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Question is answered!